Unable to send ERC20 via script using hardhat on private blockchain
I'm fairly new to solidity and web3, but here's my problem.

With geth, I have a blockchain running in POA.
In my genesisblock I have identified 3 addresses.
I connected my metamask to the chain correctly.
I've created 2 wallets from metamask (but not written in genesisblock).
I correctly deployed a smart contract (ERC20) using hardhat.
I can load the smart contract in my metamask and perform transactions between the various accounts, regardless of the address.
using hardhat, I have a script to automatically interact between 2 addresses. It's very simple:


load smart contract
approve B to spend ERC behalf on A
transferFrom(A,B,amount)
it only approve and send ERC20 from A to B.

Problem:
when trying to use the script to exchange tokens between wallets, the transaction performed with the script is correctly mined, but failsevery time. The error given is: "internal transaction awaiting".
However, with the same script, if I configure the destination address to be signer address, the transaction does not fail and the transfer takes place.
Perhaps I didn't make myself clear, but I can clarify a few points.
My questions are:

Do I have to enter all the accounts in geth?
Why, using metamask, I have no problem making a transfer, but when I use a script I do?

Regards
I tried several combination of destination adresses. Only when the destination adress is the signer, the transaction go right.
